# Creating beans when Autowiring with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I am trying to write a test for my controller. When the web service is running everything works fine. However, when I run the test I get:

`Error creating bean with name 'Controller': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.prov.Service' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

As you can see below, I believe have everything correctly Autowired and my project structure is correctly set up so that the component scanner can find the annotations properly, yet I still get this error.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @JsonView(Views.All.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/prov/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public CommonWebResponse<String> handleRequest(@RequestBody UserData userData) {
        return service.prov(userData);  
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private Repo repo;

    @Autowired
    private OtherService otherService;

    public CommonWebResponse<String> prov(UserData userData) {
        // do stuff here
        return new SuccessWebResponse<>("Status");
    }
}
```

Controller Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(
        controllers = Controller.class,
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(
                        type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                        value = {CorsFilter.class, AuthenticationFilter.class}
                )
        }
)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
public class ControllerTest {

    public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void connectToEndpoint_shouldReturnTrue() {
        UserData userData = new UserData("a", "bunch", "of", "fields");
        try {
            mvc.perform(post("/api/prov/users").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                    .content(asJsonString(userData))
                    .accept(MediaType.ALL))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Controller class autowires your Service class. Therefore, testing the Controller class requires existence of your Service class because Controller depends on creating a bean of type Service. This means you either have to `@Autowired` your service class into your test, or (preferably) mock it using something like [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/).

(edit with code example):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    private Service service

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void foo() {
        String somePayload = "Hello, World";
        String myParams = "foo";
        when(service.method(myParams)).thenReturn(somePayload);
        mvc.perform(get("my/url/to/test").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", is(equalTo("Hello, World"))));
    }
}
```

Do note that this example uses Hamcrest for things like `is()` and `equalTo()`

Comment: Thank you, I had tried to mock the service before with `@MockBean`, but I hadn't used `Mockito` to mock the actual call to the service. The only difference between my final method and what you provided is that my params and payload are custom class objects and I don't use the last line: `.andExpect(jsonPath("$", is(equalTo("Hello, World"))));` since I only need to show that the endpoint is accessible.

Comment: I added those just to demonstrate how you could potentially check the values that the Controller returns. Happy to help!